# XSD: If element has a specific value, another should be optional

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have an XML document which is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html2filename xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../xsd/mapper.xsd">
    <htmlFile filename="N5670A">
        <variant>1</variant>
        <groups>
            <group>
                <name>Removing thermostat</name>
            </group>
            <someOtherElements>asdasd</someOtherElements>
        </groups>
    </htmlFile>
</html2filename>
```

Now element "groups" -> "group" -> "name" -> should have one constraint: It should be optional if "variant" has the value 3. If not it should be required.

Can XSD handle that? If yes, how?

Comment: You should use XSD 1.1 [See here some examples](http://www.datypic.com/books/defxmlschema/chapter14.html)

Comment: Rollback explanation:  You've change your XML document, added an XSD that was different than described, and not included (let alone adapted) the xs:assert that I provided. The XSD I provided was correct for your original question, and I confirmed validation against your original XML document. Please post a new question if you need further help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

### XSD 1.1

An `xs:assert` can implement such a value-sensitive constraint:

```
            <xs:assert test="(variant = 3) or groups/group/name"/>
```

**Here it is in the context of a complete XSD that will validate the XML you provided:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
  vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:element  name="html2filename">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="htmlFile">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="variant"/>
              <xs:element name="groups">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="group" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="name" minOccurs="0"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="someOtherElements"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="filename"/>
            <xs:assert test="(variant = 3) or groups/group/name"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>    
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Please see my updated answer. After adding `<xs:assert test="(variant = 3) or groups/group/name"/>` my validator says: Can not load XML Schema.

Comment: I've rolled back your changes.  Please see my explanation in the comment to the question.  Make sure you are using an XSD 1.1 capable validating parser.  If your trouble is deeper than that, please post a new question with the smallest example that illustrates your difficulty.  Thank you.

Comment: As I already posted I get an error after using your code: "S4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The Content Of '#AnonType_HTMLFileHTMLVideoMapper' Is Invalid. Element 'assert' Is Invalid, Misplaced, Or Occurs Too Often."

Comment: Validated online, with eclipse and notepad

Comment: If you received that error message with the XSD 1.1 code listed in this answer, then your XML processors do not support XSD 1.1.  Try Xerces2-J 2.11, Oxygen, XMLSpy, Saxon-EE, etc.  You can't just guess, especially while learning XSD 1.1 because you won't know whether the mistake is yours or that the processor simply doesn't support XSD 1.1.

Comment: However that is not a solution if the element is not allowed in variant 3 but otherwise optional. Currently you enforce that it exists in a different variant than 3

Comment: Not sure why you're back three months later with an objection, but **the answer meets your original constraint**: *Now element "groups" -> "group" -> "name" -> should have one constraint: It should be optional if "variant" has the value 3. If not it should be required.*